# Javascript check if value exsist in two arrays return missing value

Tags: javascript, arrays, include

I'd like to know IF a value is missing which one is missing.

Array1: You have these values at the moment

```
['cloud:user', 'cloud:admin']
```

Array2: You need to have these values in order to continue

```
['cloud:user', 'cloud:admin', 'organization:user']
```

Current method which returns true or false. But I'd like to know IF a value is missing which one is missing. For example: 'organization:user'. If nothing is missing return true.

```
let authorized = roles.every(role => currentResourcesResult.value.includes(role));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simplest code for array intersection in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method and check whether [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) of elements of `arr1` is **not** equal to an element of an `arr2`:

```
const missingValues = arr2.filter(f => !arr1.some(s => s ==f));
```

An example:

```js
let arr1 = ['cloud:user', 'cloud:admin']
let arr2 = ['cloud:user', 'cloud:admin', 'organization:user'];
const missingValues = arr2.filter(f => !arr1.some(s => s ==f));
console.log(missingValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check it by using `Array.prototye.filter()`.

```js
const domain = ['cloud:user', 'cloud:admin', 'organization:user'];
const data = ['cloud:user', 'cloud:admin'];

const notInDomain = domain.filter(item => data.indexOf(item) === -1);

if (notInDomain.length > 0) {
  console.log('Some values are not in the domain set');
}

console.log(notInDomain);
```

### Update

You can gain the same result by using `includes` instead of `indexOf`.

```
const notInDomain = domain.filter(item => !data.includes(item));
```